# Several Audio streams while making a call

Tags: android, audio, stream, android-mediaplayer, phone-call

I am looking for the most correct way (or just any way) to play sound in several streams while making a call. For example, while calling sound goes out of internal speaker, but I need to play music from both speakers at a time. Also I need to play it from different sources(one from call , another one from external source).
I have tried to do this, but I am got simultaneous playing music and outgoing call. Here is my code.

```
case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK:
    Log.i(LOG_TAG, "onCallStateChanged: CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK");
    Toast.makeText(mContext,"Before waiting an answer",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    audioManager = (AudioManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
    try {
        //Answer waiting simulation
        Thread.sleep(5000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    Toast.makeText(mContext,"After waiting an answer",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    mp = MediaPlayer.create(mContext, Uri.parse(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/Music/celldweller.mp3"));
    /*audioManager.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_IN_CALL);
      audioManager.setSpeakerphoneOn(true);*/
    mp.start();
    break;
```

By the way, it plays several sound streams together without any lags) 
I need to play my mp3 file in another stream and from the external speaker.
Is there any way to do this using default API or reflection, or if it isn't possible using standard features , maybe there any ability to do this using native interface or editing system files or changing firmware at worst.
Thanks